# verilog error left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga

I have a verilog as module I get the error

`Error (10137): Verilog HDL Procedural Assignment error object "result" on`

`left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type`

If I add also `reg [31:0] result;`, I get another error

```
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant 
drivers for net "tempreg[0][31]" at mips_core_testbench.v(55)
.
.
.
.
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant 
drivers for net "tempreg[0][14]" at mips_core_testbench.v(55)
Error (12153): Can't elaborate top-level user hierarchy
```

Code:

```
module testbench (result, input_instruction, rs_content, rt_content);
    output [31:0] result;
    //reg [31:0] result;
    input [31:0] input_instruction;
    input [31:0] rs_content;
    input [31:0] rt_content;
    reg [31:0] tempreg [0:31];
    integer type;
    integer i;  

initial begin
    tempreg[0] = 1;
for (i = 1; i <= 31; i = i + 1)
        tempreg[i] <= 0;

end

    always@ (input_instruction) begin
        if(input_instruction[31:26] == 6'b000000)
            type = 1; // R-type
        else
            type = 0; // I-type
    end

    always@ (type) begin
        case(input_instruction[5:0])
            //add
            6'b100000:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] + tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]];
            //sub
            6'b100010:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] - tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]];
            //and
            6'b100100:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] & tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]];
            //or
            6'b100101:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] | tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]];
            //sra
            6'b000011:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] >>> input_instruction[10:6];
            //srl
            6'b000010:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] >> input_instruction[10:6];
            //sll
            6'b000010:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] << input_instruction[10:6];
            //sltu------
            //6'b101011:


        endcase
    end

        always@ (!type) begin
        case(input_instruction[31:26])
            //addi
            6'b001000:
            tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] + tempreg[input_instruction[15:0]];
            //addiu----
            //6'b001001:
            //andi
            6'b001100:
            tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] & tempreg[input_instruction[15:0]];
            //ori
            6'b001101:
            tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] | tempreg[input_instruction[15:0]];
            //slti
            6'b001010:
                begin
                    if (tempreg[input_instruction[15:0]] - tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] > 0 )          
                        tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] = 1;
                    else
                        tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] = 0;
                end
            //lui
            6'b001111:
            tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] = tempreg[input_instruction[15:0]] << 16'b0;


        endcase
    end

    always @(type or tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] or tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]])
begin

  if (type == 1)
    result <= tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]];
  else
    result <= tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]];

end

endmodule
```

Edited code:

```
module testbench (result, input_instruction, rs_content, rt_content);
    output reg[31:0] result;
    input [31:0] input_instruction;
    input [31:0] rs_content;
    input [31:0] rt_content;
    reg [31:0] tempreg [0:31];
    integer type;
    integer i;  

initial begin
    tempreg[0] = 1;
for (i = 1; i <= 31; i = i + 1)
        tempreg[i] = 0;

end

    always@ (input_instruction) begin
        if(input_instruction[31:26] == 6'b000000)
            type = 1; // R-type
        else
            type = 0; // I-type
    end

always @ * begin
    if (type) begin
        case (input_instruction[5:0])
         //add
            6'b100000:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] + tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]];
            //sub
            6'b100010:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] - tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]];
            //and
            6'b100100:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] & tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]];
            //or
            6'b100101:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] | tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]];
            //sra
            6'b000011:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] >>> input_instruction[10:6];
            //srl
            6'b000010:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] >> input_instruction[10:6];
            //sll
            6'b000010:
            tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] = tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] << input_instruction[10:6];
            //sltu------
            //6'b101011:
        endcase
    end else begin
        case (input_instruction[31:26])
             //addi
            6'b001000:
            tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] + tempreg[input_instruction[15:0]];
            //addiu----
            //6'b001001:
            //andi
            6'b001100:
            tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] & tempreg[input_instruction[15:0]];
            //ori
            6'b001101:
            tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] = tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] | tempreg[input_instruction[15:0]];
            //slti
            6'b001010:
                begin
                    if (tempreg[input_instruction[15:0]] - tempreg[input_instruction[25:21]] > 0 )          
                        tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] = 1;
                    else
                        tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] = 0;
                end
            //lui
            6'b001111:
            tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]] = tempreg[input_instruction[15:0]] << 16'b0;
        endcase
    end
end

always @(type or tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]] or tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]])
begin

  if (type == 1)
    result = tempreg[input_instruction[15:11]];
  else
    result = tempreg[input_instruction[20:16]];

end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `result` in you module declaration to be of type `wire`. You can't assign values to wires in `always` blocks.

Instead you should declare `result` as the correct type as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747373/object-name-is-not-declared-in-verlog/33747519#33747519) StackOverflow question (thanks @Greg).

```
output [31:0] result;
reg [31:0] result;
```

This makes it of `reg` type which can be assigned in an `always` block.

---

However, this is not your only problem. You are assigning values to `temp_reg` in two different `always` blocks. This is not allowed. You can only have one driver (one `always` block or `assign` statement) for any signal. Otherwise how can it implement it in logic.

You can fix this by doing:

```
always @ * begin
    if (type) begin
        case (...)
             ...
        endcase
    end else begin
        case (...)
             ...
        endcase
    end
end
```

Comment: `output reg [31:0] result;` is not valid syntax according to any IEEE1364 or IEEE1800. Some tools allow it but it is a bad practice. I explained it on another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33747519/1959732)

Comment: I also get `Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "tempreg[0][31]" at mips_core_testbench.v(54)`

Comment: @Greg indeed, I was only glancing over the code and assumed that everything was inside the module declaration ```(output reg ...)``` as that is how I usually do it (the ANSI style one). Although granted then it should have a comma, not a semicolon. Corrected that.

Comment: @askque see my edit.

Comment: thank you for your help sir. I have edited my code. Could you look? But, when I want to compile, it is compiling so slow compared to old one. How can it be improved? @TomCarpenter

Answer (score 1):

You need `result` to be a `reg`. If you want to continue using non-ANSI then use:

```
output [31:0] result;
reg [31:0] result;
```

For ANSI header use:

```
module testbench (
  output reg [31:0] result,
  input [31:0] input_instruction,
  input [31:0] rs_content,
  input [31:0] rt_content );
```

`tempreg` as being assigned in two always blocks, which is not sunthesizable. `always @(type)` and `always @(!type)` are not working the way you are thinking. Both will trigger on a change of value, but the value itself doesn't matter. Combine into one `always @*` (we are no longer in 1995, we don't have do list the full sensitivity list).

You should be using `always @*` (or the synonyms `always @(*)`) for all combinational logic blocks, and using blocking (`=`) assignments instead of non-blocking (`<=`). Non-blocking should be used for assigning flip-flops and latches, everything else should be blocking.

Make sure every bit of `tempreg` is assigned a value in one pass of the always block. Otherwise, you are inferring level sensitive latches.

*Edit:*
Looking at your code again, your going to need a clock. `tempreg` is storing values and will not be purely combinational logic. Use the template below, and use non-blocking assignments to `tempreg`. If you don't use the clock, then you will have complex latching logic. If you don't use non-blocking, then there is a potential race condition in the Verilog simulator.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (type) begin
        case (...)
             ... // use non-blocking assignments here
        endcase
    end else begin
        case (...)
             ... // use non-blocking assignments here
        endcase
    end
end
```

---

I advice you looking into ANSI style headers. Also, try not to use `type` as a variable name, it is not forward comparable with SystemVerilog.

Comment: I have added edited code sir. But, when I compile it, It is compiling so slow. I have ever seen speed in altera. Can be the code improved? or Why is it so slow? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @askque , I updated my answer. You are going to need a clock. `tempreg` reg needs to be synchronous to work properly.

Comment: sir, when I change the always header I get the error, `Error (10161): Verilog HDL error: object "clk" is not declared` Should it be defined as input? If I define as input clk, is it enough? I have never used the posedge clk. Also, If I define input clk, I get the error `Error (10206): Verilog HDL Module Declaration error at : top module port "clk" is not found in the port list`

Comment: @askque , your need to show your code. Update your question, change the "Edited code:" section. From your description you didn't add `clk` port list but you did declare it as an input. That is the annoyance with non-ANSI, you have define the port name, direction and type on different lines; with ANSI it is all together one the same line.

Comment: clocking is really efficient for this code. I will add the clk later. Thank you but, I get the slower part. My issue is here `always @(type or registers[input_instruction[15:11]] or registers[input_instruction[20:16]])
begin

  if (type == 1)
    result = registers[input_instruction[15:11]];
  else
    result = registers[input_instruction[20:16]];

end` I try to show the specified result in `result`. I have edited as appropriate ANSI rule

Comment: All comb logic blocks should be `always @*`. *Slowness* is an entirely separate issue than your original question (are you synthesizing or simulating). I cannot tell if if you need `result` before or after the clock. If after, then flop the address needed. If before, restructure everything in to valid combinational logic. You need to structure your code, managing the synchronous and combinational division. It looks like you are making a CPU or MCU but you lumped the instruction decoder, ALU, and register components together; that's now how they are typically designed.